# Is US spelling prefered here?

Tags: discussion, spelling

Recently two questions about chil(l)i got edited to the word with single letter *L*.

Is the [US spelling](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chilli) preferred here and should be edited?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For tags, yes, though [we should set up synonyms](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) to handle multiple spellings if necessary.

For titles / bodies, it's not so crucial, so long as it's clear what the asker means. I would still recommend that we *prefer* US-english spelling just to make it easier to search, but it's not absolutely necessary - [Google will figure it out](http://www.google.com/search?q=chilli) even if [our internal search doesn't](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=chilli).

That said, I approved one of those edits, because I honestly forgot about the double-L spelling and assumed (like the editor) that it was a typo. This... Will tend to happen. Don't get too concerned about it; if you want to roll it back, go ahead.

Comment: It's fine by me (actually I didn't even know the _single-l_ spelling exists), just want to make things clear - especially since chillllllli are currently my only plants and most of my question will be related to them. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Just as I was not aware the two-L spelling was accepted anywhere!

Comment: I'm in the USA but for whatever reason Fedora always defaults to the Queen's English.  Makes sceptics.SE a pain in the neck.